# How to "unmold" a string?

Tags: rebol, rebol2

I'm using [this library](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=csv.r) to convert a block to a CSV.  However, when it encounters a string with a comma in it it molds that string.  Normally not a problem except that the curly-braces seem to confuse Excel.

So, `{This, is a test}` gets turned into `| {this | is a test} |` (each side of the comma is put into separate cells).

At first I thought I needed to escape the comma but it turns out what I need to do is turn the curly braces into quotes.  Is there a quick or REBOL-recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of 'MOLD in %csv.r is to wrap values containing commas into double quotes.

But unfortunately 'MOLD puts strings longer than 50 characters into curly braces instead of double quotes, for better readability.

I don't know how to affect this behaviour, so I would just replace 'MOLD in `Item: mold Item` and `Heading: mold Heading` with 'DBL-QUOTE, which would simply be defined as

```
dbl-quote: func[s][rejoin [{"} s {"}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [csv-tools.r](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=csv-tools.r) instead. It has that functionality built in, and is verified to be Excel compatible. It will work with Rebol 2 and 3, and has been in production use for years.

Comment: The to-csv function in csv-tools.r seems to have problems with nested blocks like `[["one" "two" "three"] ["two" "two" "three"]]`.

Comment: The `to-csv` function is a single-line converter, like the documentation in the file says. Single lines of CSV don't have nested blocks, they are conceptually series of individual values. Use the `map-each` function with `to-csv` to generate a block of lines, then `write` to write them out to a file.